# Difference between ReactClass and ReactComponent?

Tags: reactjs

In the [React Dom Terminology](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#formal-type-definition), what is the difference between ReactClass and  ReactComponent?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put:

**ReactClass**: A model or a shape for components, if you want to create a component called `DatePicker`, the *shape* is the ReactClass, not each of the individual components/instances will you create based on that shape.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

**ReactComponent** or **ReactElement**: A component instance that you create based on a pre-defined *ReactClass*. If you create a component called `DatePicker`, each *instance* of that component that is rendered is a *ReactElement*

```
var component = React.createElement(MyComponent, props);
```

Normally you don't use `React.createElement` because you can just use something like this `<MyComponent />`, but it's really useful if you want to dynamically create instances of components, like for storing in a variable and rendering them later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.  It seems like a class vs object in c++.

Answer (score 0):

I just found it from my link.
I keep this question for someone who may have the same question.
From [React Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-components),

> A ReactComponent Class is **simply just a JavaScript class** (or **"constructor function"**).

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

> When this constructor is invoked it is expected to return an **object with at least a render method on it. This object is referred to as a ReactComponent**.

```
var component = new MyComponent(props); // never do this
```